# Using a UITableViewController with a small-sized table?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

When using a UITableViewController, the initWithStyle: method automatically creates the underlying UITableView with - according to the documentation - "the correct dimensions".

My problem is that these "correct dimensions" seem 320x460 (the iPhone's screen size), but I'm pushing this TableView/Controller pair into a UINavigationController which is itself contained in a UIView, which itself is about half the height of the screen.

No frame or bounds wrangling I can come up with seems to correctly reset the table's size, and as such it's "too long", meaning there are a collection of rows that are pushed off the bottom of the screen and are not visible nor reachable by scrolling.

So my question comes down to: what is the proper way to tell a UITableViewController to resize its component UITableView to a specified rectangle?

Thanks!

**Update** I've tried all the techniques suggested here to no avail, but I did find one interesting thing: if I eschew the UINavigationController altogether (which I'm not yet willing to do for production, but as an experiment), and add the table view as a *direct* subview of the enclosing view I mentioned, the frame size given *is respected*. The **very moment** I re-introduce the UINavigationController into the mix, no matter if it is added as a subview before or after the table view, and no matter if alloc/init it before or after the table view is added as a subview, the result is the same as it was before.

I'm beginning to suspect UINavigationController isn't much of a team player...

**Update 2** The suggestion to check frame size after the table view on screen was a good one: turns out that the navigation controller is in fact resizing it some time in between load and display. My solution, hacky at best, has been to cache the frame given on load and to reset it if changed at the beginning of tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:. Why there you ask? Because it's the one place I found that worked, that's why!

I don't consider this a solution as it's obviously improper, but for the benefit of anyone else reading, it does seem to work.

Answer (score 11):

Why not just use a regular UIViewController and create the table manually?

Comment: agreed, just extend UIViewController instead, and add tableView property on your own like this
<code>
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITableView  *tableView;
</code>

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and I solved it with:

```
-(void) loadView {
    [self setView:[[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease]];
    [[self view] setAutoresizesSubviews:NO];

    /* Create & configure table and other views... */

    [self setResultsTable:[[RadarTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil]];
    [[resultsTable view] setFrame:CGRectMake(0,45,320,200)];
}
```

This is done in the parent (just a plain UIViewController in my case) controller.

Comment: Thx, my 181 px Tableview inside a UIViewController got always shrinked, now it's listening to the frame settings since I use your [[self view] setAutoresizesSubviews:NO];

Comment: A better solution would probably be to modify the table view's `autoresizingMask` property instead--make it resize its width, but not its height.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I solved it by resizing the tableView in the viewDidAppear function of the UITableViewController. Not the ideal solution but it works.

Comment: Incredible! I almost didn't even try this but this was the ONLY thing I could get to work when trying to resize the table view of a UITableViewController. All I did was set the frame of the table view in viewDidAppear and it works perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can set the top margin by using :

```
    UIEdgeInsets inset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(50, 0, 0, 0);
    self.tableView.contentInset = inset;
```

it's Not a good practice , just in case you want more space on top you can use it .

**Should not use UITableViewController , Just simply Use UIViewController and Programmatically Create UITableview**

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Ben's answer. I've often run into the situation where I need to resize a UITableVIew due to other controls on a view.

I usually just have a regular UIViewController with a UITableView IBOutlet. Then, if I need to, I can just manipulate the UITableView object's frame to get it to the size I need.

Comment: Care to elaborate on exactly how you accomplish this?

Comment: Just use normal UIViewController and - for example - programmatically, create TableView  -  UITableView *mTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,400)];
mTableView.delegate = self;
[[self view] addSubview:mTableView];

and there you have it! :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you're creating an additional view controller for your table. However, in your code, I don't see you adding the table view to its parent. You might also try reducing the bounds height until the whole thing appears on screen; once you do that, it may give you insight as to why it's not working the way you expect.

Comment: I need a view controller to be able to push onto a UINavigationController, hence why it's there. As such, I was under the impression it wasn't necessary to add the table view to the parent view, because the view controller takes care of that by proxy. Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you assigning the view outlet of MyUIViewControllerSubclass to your table, or its enclosing view?

Comment: As shown in the code I posted as an "answer", I'm definitely assigning the 'view' outlet to the table that I've just created.

Answer (score 1):

Check the autoresizingMask and contentMode properties of the UITableView.  These can both affect the frame.

Answer (score 1):

i fixed this problem by this code

```
{
    UIEdgeInsets insets;
    insets.left = 0;
    insets.right = 0;
    insets.top = 0;
    insets.bottom = 60;
    self.tableView.contentInset = insets;
    [self.tableView setScrollIndicatorInsets:insets];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Interface Builder, you can simply go to "Table View Size" properties window, and change Bottom Insets for both Content and Scroller with the height of another widget.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;

//This one in case your NavigationController is not Translucent
self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = NO;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

Set the frame in `UINavigationController`.