# Wrong size of UITableView using autoresizingMask

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, autoresize

I have a UITableView which is not being resized properly using autoresizeMask (in iPhone 3.0).

The UITableView is inside a UIViewController inside a UINavigationController inside a UITabBarController, all of which are being created programatically. The status bar is visible.

The code of the UIViewController is basically:

```
- (void)loadView {
    UIView* rootView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    self.view = rootView;
    [rootView release]; 
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // table = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480-20-49-44)];
    table = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 100)]; table.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    [self.view addSubview:table];
}
```

When created like this, the UITableView is slightly bigger than the available space. If I'm not mistaken, it's exactly 44 pixels bigger, the size of the navigation bar.

However, if I uncomment the commented line and comment the next line the size of the UITableView is exactly right. I would prefer to use autoresizingMask instead of manually calculating the size of the UITableView. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that I wasn't setting the frame of the root view in loadView. If you define such frame, and then define the frame of the subviews in relation to that frame, then the autoresize masks will correctly resize the subviews according to how the root view was resized by the framework.

For example:

```
- (void)loadView {
    UIView* rootView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
    self.view = rootView;
    [rootView release]; 
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    table = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame]; 
    table.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    [self.view addSubview:table];
}
```

Thanks to Colin Gislason who pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

The autoresizing mask will not help you with the initial size of the table view. The table view is created with the frame that you give it. The autoresizing mask defines the rules for resizing this frame relative to the parent view when the parent's frame changes.

So if I define a table that is 320x100 it will stay that size unless I change it explicitly or the parent view's frame changes.

Depending on the other views, you could do the calculation based on the other views held by the parent or by the parent's frame itself.

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply, Colin. The autoresizing mask IS doing something. The table view is being created with a 320x100 size, and yet it fills all the screen. I can change 100 to 200 and the size will be the same.

Comment: And if you don't set an autoresizing mask but still set it to 320x100, it doesn't fill the whole screen?

Comment: That's right. With no autoresizing mask set the table view is sized according to the frame.

Comment: Ok. Then the UITableViewController must be resizing the table. This questions provides evidence and maybe a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222956/using-a-uitableviewcontroller-with-a-small-sized-table

Comment: I'm not using a UITableViewController. I'm subclassing UIViewController.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. Something is going on that I can't explain then. Somewhere your table is being resized. You can experiment with the mask to verify it. If you set the frame to 100x100, and a mask that only resizes vertically it should still stay 100px wide.

Comment: If I set the frame to 100x100 and a mask that only resizes it vertically, it stays 100px wide. It seems that the only thing that is resizing the table is the autoresizingMask.

Comment: That's where my answer comes in. The autoresizing mask doesn't do the autoresizing. It only defines the rule. Whatever resizes it (usually the parent UIView) is obeying that rule. When a view is resized, it resizes it's children, which then resize their children all the way down the hierarchy. The Apple documentation explains a bit: http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/autoresizingMask

Answer (score 0):

Create UIViewController subclass instand of UITableViewController Subclass.

insert UITableView instance.

in NIB simply drag and drop UIView

on top of that wier place the existing UITableVIew object.

set the size of the uitableview via nib or viewDidLoad method.

set the reference , dataSource and delegate via nib.

now its simply transfer the UIViewController class and the can change tableview size as you wish.

Comment: hi Claus,
 i try it with dynamic content. but it will work with static content...