# Change TableView Size When It has AN XIB

Tags: ios, uitableview

My UITableViewController class uses an .xib.  I would like to make the TableView only take up half the size of the screen, so that I could add more to it.  Is there anyway to do this, or do I need to create it all in code, and not use .xib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222956/using-a-uitableviewcontroller-with-a-small-sized-table) covers a similar situation.  In practice it would be easier to use a standard `UIViewController` and implement the `UITableViewDataSource` and `Delegate` methods manually.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot resize the UITableViewController class,if you want to add something under table place it at it's footer.

You Can also declare UITableView in UIViewController through XIB through which you can resize it.

in .h File
IBOutlet UITableView *tView;
 and connect it to file owner

Thanks